# Having trouble declaring overloaded operator in c++ head file

Tags: c++, class, vector, struct, header

So I am making a program that will do some operations with polynomials and I am using a vector full of a struct I defined to represent a polynomial. Part of what I am trying to do is to overload the +,-,*.+=,-= and *= operators.

term is a struct I defined.

I am trying to contain all of the overload methods within a class.

I have a single file that overloads it and works fine. The method is defined as:

```
vector<term> operator+(vector<term> t1, vector<term> t2)
```

When I try and put that in a c++ header file to use it in a class I get this error:

Method declaration in header:

```
vector<term> operator+(vector<term> v1,vector<term> v2);
```

Error I get:

```
poly.h:25:71: error: ‘std::vector<term> Polynomial::operator+(std::vector<term>, std::vector<term>)’ must take either zero or one argument
     vector<term> operator+(const vector<term> v1,const vector<term> v2);
```

Why would it work in one instance and not the other?

I am new to c++ so forgive if I miss any blatant mistakes.

Comment: you can use `const vector<term> &v2` (and v1, depending on what you implement) to speed up your process (passing by reference instead of copying)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message:

> > std::vector Polynomial::operator+(std::vector, std::vector) [...]

I deduce that you declared `operator +()` as a member of class `Polynomial`. As a member of this class, it must take either zero or one argument (as the message says).

The overload taking zero argument is called when evaluating the expression `+p` for some `p` of type `Polynomial`. The overload taking one argument of type say, `std::vector<term>`, is used when evaluating the expression `p + q` where `p` has type `Polynomial` and `q` has type `std::vector<term>` (or anything implicitly convertible to it).

It looks like that you need this function

```
vector<term> operator+(vector<term> v1,vector<term> v2);
```

to be declared and defined outside any class. It might be either in the global namespace (not advisable) or inside the namespace containing `term` (preferable).

In addition, I would expect the correct declaration to be

```
vector<term> operator+(const vector<term>& v1, const vector<term>& v2);
```

since inside this function you (probably) don't need to make a copy of either operand to work on and you just need reading access to them.

Answer (score 2):

The error is because `operator+()` is a member function of a class, `Polynomial` in this case. What you can do is make `operator+()` a free function, which in this case allows you to pass two arguments. 
Because your function is a member function, this means it will take three different values. Two of them are the ones you pass, and the third one is `this`, which is implicit.

If you want to keep it as a member function, you need to make the function take only one argument. The second argument will be passed as `this`.

Comment: Thanks! So I'd have to do this for every overloaded operator?

Comment: Yes the other operators as well.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from information you provided, you try to redefine operator +.
Let me clarify: while inside of a class definition you can **declare** a function and it will automagically be assigned to that class. Yet when you are **defining** a function (what overloaded operator actually is) you have to explicitly tell your compiler, that you are refering to a function belonging to your class. Scope resolution operator `::` does just that.
So I think you just need to use `vector<term> **classname**::operator+(vector<term> t1, vector<term> t2)`